# Ruby on Rails variable presenting Active Record data instead of integer in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, activerecord, view, block

I expected two values in a helper calculated from Active Record data that are being presented in the same view, 'gross_income_upload' and 'all_time_gross'.
Gross income is OK, but all time gross integer is not being shown, what is being presented instead is the Active Record array data.

There is a helper function and an .erb view with the following codes:

Application Helper (application_helper.rb):

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def gross_income_upload
    if Sale.any?
      gross_income_upload = Sale.last.purchase_count*Sale.last.item_price
    else
      gross_income_upload = 0
    end
  end

  def all_time_gross
    if Sale.any?
      all_time_gross = 0
      sales = Sale.all
      sales.each do |sale|
        all_time_gross = all_time_gross + sale.purchase_count*sale.item_price
      end
    else
      all_time_gross = 0
    end
  end

end
```

User info view (_user_info.html.erb):

```
<h1>Gross income uploaded: R$<%= gross_income_upload %></h1>
<h2>All time gross: R$<%= all_time_gross %></h2>
```

Last gross income in variable 'gross_income_upload' is the income from last sale and is calculated in function by:

```
gross_income_upload = Sale.last.purchase_count*Sale.last.item_price
```

Gross income uploaded is OK, 'gross_income_upload' is 'R$20.0', it is being well presented in the view.

```
Gross income uploaded: R$20.0
```

What is not ok is the other value, 'all_time_gross'.

The result expected is the calculation inside the loop, 'all_time_gross' is measured by the sum of sale purchase_count multiplied by item_price of every entry in database:

```
sales.each do |sale|
    all_time_gross = all_time_gross + sale.purchase_count*sale.item_price
```

Instead of the integer, the value in the view is the Active Record array data:

```
All time gross: R$[#<Sale id: 1, purchaser_name: "João Silva", item_description: "R$10 off R$20 of food", item_price: 10.0, purchase_count: 2, merchant_address: "987 Fake St", merchant_name: "Bob's Pizza\n", created_at: "2021-08-30 03:11:57.639361000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-08-30 03:11:57.639361000 +0000">, #<Sale id: 2, purchaser_name: "Amy Pond", item_description: "R$30 of awesome for R$10", item_price: 10.0, purchase_count: 5, merchant_address: "456 Unreal Rd", merchant_name: "Tom's Awesome Shop\n", created_at: "2021-08-30 03:11:58.496490000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-08-30 03:11:58.496490000 +0000">, #<Sale id: 3, purchaser_name: "Marty McFly", item_description: "R$20 Sneakers for R$5", item_price: 5.0, purchase_count: 1, merchant_address: "123 Fake St", merchant_name: "Sneaker Store Emporium\n", created_at: "2021-08-30 03:11:58.593304000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-08-30 03:11:58.593304000 +0000">, #<Sale id: 4, purchaser_name: "Snake Plissken", item_description: "R$20 Sneakers for R$5", item_price: 5.0, purchase_count: 4, merchant_address: "123 Fake St", merchant_name: "Sneaker Store Emporium\n", created_at: "2021-08-30 03:11:58.696714000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-08-30 03:11:58.696714000 +0000">]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby implicitly returns the result of the last operation in a method. In `all_time_gross`, when there are `Sale` objects, you are setting a variable but you don't actually return it. The last operation in that execution path is `sales.each`, which (when given a block) returns the enumerated set/range after iterating:

```rb
def all_time_gross
  if Sale.any?
    ...
    # The result of this is *not* all_time_gross
    sales.each do |sale|
      all_time_gross = all_time_gross + sale.purchase_count*sale.item_price
    end
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

That's why you are ending up with an array of your `Sale` objects. At a very simplistic level, the solution to your problem is to ensure that `all_time_gross` is the last thing in your method:

```rb
def all_time_gross
  if Sale.any?
    all_time_gross = 0
    sales = Sale.all
    sales.each do |sale|
      all_time_gross = all_time_gross + sale.purchase_count*sale.item_price
    end
  else
    all_time_gross = 0
  end
  all_time_gross # ensures value returned
end
```

**However**, your method (actually both) can be significantly simplified, which lessens the possibility of such bugs creeping in. In the case of `all_time_gross`, you can use the `.sum` method to handle the calculation:

```rb
def all_time_gross
  # Just bail out if there's nothing to do
  return 0 unless Sale.any?

  # Prefer .find_each over .all.each because it batches queries
  Sale.find_each.sum { |sale| sale.purchase_count * sale.item_price } 
end
```

In `gross_income_upload`, you also don't really need to assign a value to a variable since you are just immediately returning the result. Instead you could do something like:

```rb
def gross_income_upload
  return 0 unless Sale.any?

  # In your version, calling Sale.last twice causes two queries
  # for the same object
  sale = Sale.last
  sale.purchase_count * sale.item_price
end
```